# Calling a C++ dll file in FORTRAN, by creating C wrapper around C++ interface

Tags: c++, c, dll, fortran

I have been tasked with the responsibility of developing a piece of code in FORTRAN, which will call a .dll file written in C++ and use the subroutines in the dll file for calculation. 
I had mailed the developers of the .dll file regarding the possibility of such an implementation. Below is the reply for the developer

> This interface would be impossible to call from FORTRAN directly.
>   It would be possible to create a standard C wrapper around the C++ class interface, and then call the standard C from FORTRAN (with a compiler that could link to and call Visual Studio .dlls)."

Myself being an amateur in working with dlls, any help (links to tutorials, example code) would be appreciated.

Status till now: Since I do not have the source code for the dll file, I had performed dumpbin and extracted the names of the functions.

Comment: There is a whole tag [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding] here about interfacing Fortran and C. C++ just adds `extern "C"` to that. Thare are many questions and answers about C++ in that tag too. It is not clear from your question if Fortran calls C++ or opposite or both.

Comment: @VladimirF it says "developing a piece of code in FORTRAN, which will call a .dll file written in C++ and use the subroutines in the dll file for calculation." , so it looks very clear to me that he wants to call a C++ function from his fortran code.  My question is, could you make your main project in C and then call the C++ dll and his Fortran subroutines as libraries?

Comment: @Slex OK, I became lost when I read that. Regarding your other point, why would you introduce such a complication?

Answer (score 1):

You create a series of C++ functions, each declared `extern "C"`, to be called from Fortran. To build them, you need the header file for the DLL; you include it, and you write whatever C++ code you have to write to map from a simple, fortran-callable, function to the API advertised by the DLL.

Comment: An update. 
I created a .lib file using the dumpbin command and created a static library project in C++, created a file called "extern.hpp", declared **extern "C"** before the names of the functions. Tried compiling them, and indeed they were compiled. But the .lib file was not generated. Am I doing something wrong, or should I take a whole new approach altogether?